# What is the idiomatic way to do something when an Option is either None, or the inner value meets some condition?

Tags: rust

Is there a more idiomatic way to express something like the following?

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut foo: Option<u8> = None;
    match foo {
        Some(foo_val) if ! (foo_val < 5) /* i.e. the negation of my acceptance condition */ => {}
        _ => { foo.replace(5); }
    }
}
```

It seems like most of the time there's an alternative to having an arm that doesn't do anything, but I've been unable to find one for this particular case.

What I'd like to say is the more direct `if foo.is_none() || /* some way to extract and test the inner value */ { ... }`, or perhaps some chaining trick that's eluding me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Rust 1.70.0 (2023-06-02), [`Option::is_some_and`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.is_some_and) can be used. It has been built for the opposite use case as in the question: returning `false` if it is `None`:

```
if foo.is_some_and(|foo_val| foo_val < 5) { 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In terms of the question, this would come out to be `foo.is_none() || foo.is_some_and(...)`. I'm not very good at reading assembly, but it looks like the compiler is smart enough to collapse the double pattern match in release mode (see release ASM on [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=e8b4bfa7392818a86201ec960f2fbadf)). This is bar none the most readable answer.

Answer (score 57):

```
//        in None case
//             │       in Some(_) case
//            ┌┴─┐  ┌───────────────────┐    
if foo.map_or(true, |foo_val| foo_val < 5) {
    // ...
}
```

For more information see [`Option::map_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or).

Comment: I've been using rust for a good while, and I doubt I'd understand this if I encountered it in the wild. (Looking at the other answers, I suspect there is no real idiomatic way of doing this…)

Comment: Yep, I agree, it's not the most intuitive or easy to read solution. Sure, if you see it a hundred times, your brain starts to understand the pattern. But I also have to actively think about this construct still.

Comment: A hundred times?  I'm not sure, once you know what an `Option<T>` is it seems fairly intuitive what this method should do.  As an exercise I once implemented an `Option` class in C# and added this method without knowing it existed in Rust, it just made sense to be there.

Comment: Potentially more readable: `foo.map(|foo_val| foo_val < 5).unwrap_or(true)`

Comment: @Caesar it can help to remember the single fact that `Option`s and `Result`s have a lot in common with iterators. Unlike `Vec`s, which can iterate over any number of elements, `Option`s can iterate over either 0 or 1 elements. Granted, `map_or` is not an `Iterator` method, but knowing this fact makes me remember to at least *look* for functions based on map and filter semantics.

Comment: @Caesar There's a first time for everything. If we only ever wrote code that's line-by-line understandable to the broadest audience possible, then all code would be bloated, inexpressive code: a wall of text where one can understand what each line is doing, but has to work to figure out the big picture (what it's actually trying to accomplish). Code should be written to make sense to the intended audience - to the team working on it, or if a library, to people who have some experience in the domain it covers. It shouldn't by default target a general programmer audience of all backgrounds.

Answer (score 28):

There are many ways to do it. One of the simplest (and arguably most readable) is something like this:

```
if foo.unwrap_or(0) < 5 {
    ...
}
```

The above will be true in both cases:

- when `foo` is `Some` with a value smaller than `5`;
- when `foo` is `None`.

In some more complex scenarios, where the "default" value needs to be calculated and performance is critical, you might want to consider [`unwrap_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else).

As Lukas suggested, the [`map_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or) method can also be used. Note that arguments passed to `map_or` are eagerly evaluated, so if performance is critical, you might want to consider [`map_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or_else) as an alternative.

### Rust 1.70+

The [`is_some_and`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.is_some_and) method has been stabilized in Rust 1.70. Here is an example:

```
if name.is_some_and(|s| s.len() > 50) {
    println!("This is a long name!");
}
```

In many cases that should be more readable than [`map_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or) / [`map_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or_else).

Answer (score 15):

You can do it with [`filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.filter) (using the negation of your condition) and [`is_none`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.is_none):

```
if foo.filter(|&x| !(x < 5)).is_none() {
    // Here either foo was None or it contained a value less than 5
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question but you can try something like that:

```rust
fn main() {
    let foo: Option<u8> = None;
    let result = foo.filter(|foo_val| !(*foo_val < 5) ).unwrap_or(5);
    println!("Result: {result}");
}
```

More example on [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4c0db286a51f0d38206b54445c20d8f1)

Answer (score 6):

The [matches!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.matches.html) macro seems like a good fit:

```
if matches!(foo, Some(a) if a>=5) { foo.replace(5) }
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9f7b37c97b895bab52a46defd956368a)

Comment: It's interesting that this basically expands to the question example but is so much more concise. Seems clearer than any of the two step answers.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Travis It jumps into my eyes immediately and I don't like it. But this is just a personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

I'll throw in another solution just for fun....

```
foo = foo.
    or(Some(5)). // if None return Some(5)
    map(|x| if x<5 { 5 } else { x });
```

or (for this specific example)

```
foo = foo.
    or(Some(5)). // if None return Some(5)
    map(|x| u8::max(x, 5));
```

Answer (score 3):

With `filter` and `or`,

```
foo = foo.filter(|a|  *a >= 5)
                .or(Some(5));
```